# try to print to a star bluetooth printer with jquery

Tags: jquery, printing, bluetooth

i am in mobile app and i want to print to a star bluetooth printer. Star has an SDK which includes a .jar library called StarIOPort3.1.jar which is responsible for opening/closing the printer port, getting status, and sending print jobs to the printer.

Also Star SDK has a demo app with all the functionality of the printer.

In this demo app the printing function is as follows

```
    public void ShowTextFormating(View view)
    {
        EditText portNameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_PortName);
        portName = portNameField.getText().toString();

    CheckBox portSettingsCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_PortablePrinter);
    portSettings = "";
    if(portSettingsCheckBox.isChecked() == true)
    {
        portSettings = "mini";
    }

    if(portSettingsCheckBox.isChecked() == true)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, textFormatingMiniActivity.class);
        startActivityFromChild(this, myIntent, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, textFormatingActivity.class);
        startActivityFromChild(this, myIntent, 0);
    }
}
```

which call textFormatingMiniActivity.class if portable printer checkbox is checked.

textFormatingMiniActivity.class is as follows

```
package com.StarMicronics.StarIOSDK;

import com.StarMicronics.StarIOSDK.PrinterFunctions.Alignment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class textFormatingMiniActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mini_textformating);

        Spinner spinner_height = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_height);
        SpinnerAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"});
        spinner_height.setAdapter(ad);

        Spinner spinner_width = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_width);
        ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"});
        spinner_width.setAdapter(ad);

        Spinner spinner_alignment = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_alignment);
        ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {"Left", "Center", "Right"});
        spinner_alignment.setAdapter(ad);
    }

    public void PrintText(View view)
    {
        String portName = StarIOSDKActivity.getPortName();
        String portSettings = StarIOSDKActivity.getPortSettings();

        CheckBox checkbox_underline = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_underline);
        boolean underline = checkbox_underline.isChecked();

        CheckBox checkbox_emphasized = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_emphasized);
        boolean emphasized = checkbox_emphasized.isChecked();

        CheckBox checkbox_upsidedown = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chechbox_upsidedown);
        boolean upsidedown = checkbox_upsidedown.isChecked();

        CheckBox checkbox_invertColor = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_invertcolor);
        boolean invertColor = checkbox_invertColor.isChecked();

        Spinner spinner_height = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_height);
        byte height = (byte) spinner_height.getSelectedItemPosition();

        Spinner spinner_width = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_width);
        byte width = (byte) spinner_width.getSelectedItemPosition();


        EditText edittext_leftmargin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_leftmargin);
        int leftMargin = 0;
        try
        {
            leftMargin = Integer.parseInt(edittext_leftmargin.getText().toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            leftMargin = 0;
        }

        Spinner spinner_alignment = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_alignment);
        PrinterFunctions.Alignment alignment = PrinterFunctions.Alignment.Left;
        switch(spinner_alignment.getSelectedItemPosition())
        {
        case 0:
            alignment = Alignment.Left;
            break;
        case 1:
            alignment = Alignment.Center;
            break;
        case 2:
            alignment = Alignment.Right;
        }

        EditText edittext_texttoprint = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_TextToPrint);
        byte[] texttoprint = edittext_texttoprint.getText().toString().getBytes();

        MiniPrinterFunctions.PrintText(this, portName, portSettings, underline, emphasized, upsidedown, invertColor, height, width, leftMargin, alignment, texttoprint);
    }
```

This is my question:

How to call MiniPrinterFunctions.PrintText from jquery cause my app is written in Jquery...

Is there any other way to print to this printer from jquery using the above code

please help

thx in advance